# Synology NAS Sync to Mac with encrypted folder

Tags: encryption, synology

I have two desktop machines and one laptop sync files with my Synology NAS.

My laptop is a Mac and I would like to protect my sync folder in case someone steal the laptop or I loose it. So the nice to have is that in order to access the sync folder in my laptop I need to enter a password. Because if I encrypt the folder then the sync tool won't be able to keep sync the files from my NAS.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this the wrong way. Instead of just encrypting this one folder, just enable FileVault2 and encrypt the whole drive.